# Force Element Above Another When Z-Index is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

So I have done about 2 hours of research about this topic, and all the answers I found where too vague for me to follow or where not answered. So I have made this topic.

**So the problem that I have run into is the following:**

Due to the way that HTML/CSS works some elements cannot be placed over each other using `z-index` when hovered over. And due to the situation I do not think it is possible for me to modify my HTML to avoid this. I need 3 elements to become above each other when hovered over. I used `:hover {z-index:1000}` but this had no effect at all. I do not know why.

I will post my code so you may be able to diagnose what is causing this, or let me know that I am doing it wrong because z-index does not work in the situation and that I need to do something else.

**Now, to clarify:** Z-index is not working for me in the situation, how can I get the same effect or fix something to get it working, can I use JavaScript or jQuery to fix this?

```css
.banner-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.four.columns {
  position: relative;
  left: 13%;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  border: 5px solid #f2f5f8;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
#image-port {
  position: absolute;
  top: 550px;
}
#banner1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0s, height 0s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 0s, height 0s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  z-index: 0;
}
#banner1:hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 125%;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: -21px;
  border: 5px solid #f2f5f8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#banner2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0s, height 0s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 0s, height 0s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  z-index: 0;
}
#banner2:hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 125%;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: -21px;
  border: 5px solid #f2f5f8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#banner3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0s, height 0s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 0s, height 0s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  z-index: 0;
}
#banner3:hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 125%;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: -21px;
  border: 5px solid #f2f5f8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="ten columns" id="image-port">
  <div class="four columns">
    <div class="banner-container">
      <img src="images/banners/1.png" id="banner1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="four columns">
    <div class="banner-container">
      <img src="images/banners/2.png" id="banner2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="four columns">
    <div class="banner-container">
      <img src="images/banners/3.png" id="banner3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain this part with some other words and in more detail? "I need 3 elements to become above each other when hovered over".

Comment: z-index only works when elements are in the same context, i.e. it won't work for floated over relative position, it won't work for absolute vs floated... This is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Try to target the div with your z-index and :hover

Comment: Ok! These need to be above each other when hovered over! http://prntscr.com/8u8num and http://prntscr.com/8u8obc and http://prntscr.com/8u8oh8 And @ryan so how can I solve this?

Comment: @turbopipp Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readership images were not rising to the top when hovered over because their grand parent divisions were both positioned and given a stacking context. Hovering over images changed their z-index within their grand parent's context without changing the z-position of the grand parent itself.

Not giving the grand parent a stacking context  using the CSS rule

`.four.column { z-index: auto}`

would appear to fix the problem.